# SQL Query: how to return a column of substrings from a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I've tried the answers in similar questions and they weren't working for me.  I have a column of text that has substrings which I am interested in.  I want to make a new column with these substrings.

**person_table:**

| person_details |
| --- |
| Name: John Doe, DoB: 1973-04-15, Address: 123 Main St |
| Name: Jane Doe, DoB: 1982-03-24, Address: 123 Main St, Occupation: Developer |
| Name: James Smith, DoB: 1990-07-07 |

**Desired:**

| person_details | DoB |
| --- | --- |
| Name: John Doe, DoB: 1973-04-15, Address: 123 Main St | 1973-04-15 |
| Name: Jane Doe, DoB: 1982-03-24, Address: 123 Main St, Occupation: Developer | 1982-03-24 |
| Name: James Smith, DoB: 1990-07-07 | 1990-07-07 |

This is a simplified example. I don't know which position in the string the middle name will start with so I need to search for a pattern.

I've tried the following:

```
select person_details, regexp_extract(person_details, "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])") as DoB
from person_table;

select person_details, extract(person_details, "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])") as DoB
from person_table;

select person_details, regexp_substr(person_details, "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])") as DoB
from person_table;
```

But these all give me errors.

How can I get this new column?

Comment: Why don't you have proper columns in the table for each detail, instead of storing it as a single string?

Comment: I didnt make the table. I hope that the engineers get around to parsing the details out into a structured format but for now I need to get it out myself.  I could get it into a pandas dataframe in python and apply a function to parse it but I would rather do that all in one query

Comment: There's no `regexp_extract()` function in Oracle. `extract` is for extracting a part of a `DATETIME` value (e.g. just the year or month). But `regexp_substr()` should have worked, what was the error?

Comment: It is possible that you receive the data from an outside source, in single-string format (one string per row), and you must process the data yourself. If that is the case, see if you can ask the providers of data to use a structured string format; from what you show, it should be just as easy to send the data to you as JSON strings. Then you could use JSON tools in the Oracle database. (This is exactly why JSON was invented, for this type of scenario.)

Answer (score 1):

This is... not a great way to store data for a whole variety of reasons.  Parsing the data at runtime every time is going to be slow, indexing this is going to be very, very difficult, etc.  At least if you stored the compound data as JSON or XML, depending on the Oracle version, there are some built-in functions to parse and index JSON and XML so you aren't completely without tools.  But even then, you'd almost certainly want to parse out the commonly used fields when you're loading the data.

I'd use a [simple `instr` and `substr`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be19ebc7191b3e0a9200e027030140d5).  Assuming that you can just look for the string "DoB: " and the date is always 10 characters in length, you can do something like this.

```
with p as (
  select 'Name: John Doe, DoB: 1973-04-15, Address: 123 Main St' person_details from dual union all
  select 'Name: Jane Doe, DoB: 1982-03-24, Address: 123 Main St, Occupation: Developer' from dual union all
  select 'Name: James Smith, DoB: 1990-07-07' from dual
)
select substr( person_details, instr( person_details, 'DoB: ')+5, 10 ) dob
  from p
```

If the date isn't always 10 characters, you could look for the first comma after the "DoB: " in the string and use that to calculate the length.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Probably not the most efficient way, but it get the job done.

```
declare @person_table TABLE(personInfo nvarchar(200))
```

insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: John Doe, DoB: 1973-04-15, Address: 123 Main St')
insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: Jane Doe, DoB: 1982-03-24, Address: 123 Main St, Occupation: Developer')
insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: James Smith, DoB: 1990-07-07');

select personinfo,
case
WHEN personInfo like '%DoB%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
/* Please note that +5 in the CHARINDEX is the length of 'DoB: ' and 10 is the string length of the DoB*/
THEN substring(personInfo,CHARINDEX('DoB: ',personInfo)+5,10) else 'No DoB' end DoB
from @person_table

Answer (score 0):

Just want to reformat the code

```
declare @person_table TABLE(personInfo nvarchar(200))

insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: John Doe, DoB: 1973-04-15, Address: 123 Main St')
insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: Jane Doe, DoB: 1982-03-24, Address: 123 Main St, Occupation: Developer')
insert into @person_table (personInfo) values('Name: James Smith, DoB: 1990-07-07');

select personinfo, 
    case
        WHEN personInfo like '%DoB%[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%' 
            /* Please note that +5 in the CHARINDEX is the length of 'DoB: ' and 10 is the string length of the DoB*/
            THEN substring(personInfo,CHARINDEX('DoB: ',personInfo)+5,10) else 'No DoB' end DoB 
from @person_table
```